# Literature search engine including citation count, year, and the conference presented at

Tags: computer-science, google-scholar, literature-search

When I am searching for literature on a particular topic, I'd like to see a list of results together with three main pieces of information: citation count, year, and publication venue (i.e., conference or journal name). In my field (Computer Science), most papers are published in conferences. The conference name is an easy way to assess at a glance: (i) the general area the paper falls into (systems, theory, programming languages, etc.) (ii) the quality of the contribution (higher-tier conferences are associated with higher quality research). Citation count also helps to assess (ii), but is less effective for more recent or more obscure papers.

**My question:** Is there a literature search tool (software or website) that can be used to provide **citation count, year, and conference** in a list of results?

**Tools I have tried:** I currently use [Google Scholar](https://scholar.google.com) (it provides citations favors highly cited articles when returning search results), but it usually does not provide conference information correctly (this may be because it gets cut off). For example, it lists a paper of mine from "LIPIcs-Leibniz International..." and makes it hard to identify the conference, which is "International Conference on Automata, Languages and Programming (ICALP)". In contrast, [DBLP](https://dblp.uni-trier.de/) is designed specifically for Computer Science, so it does a good job of telling me the conference; however, it does not list citation count.

If it is possible to fix the result list with Google Scholar so that it provides the conference information more helpfully, that could be an answer to my question as well.

Comment: Web of Science certainly has all of those in the results.

Comment: @JonCuster I can't find any concrete info, but I can't find any conference proceedings on Web of Science. This is the vast majority of computer science literature. Maybe I am doing the search wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For computer science, the [ACM Digital Library](https://dl.acm.org) seems to be exactly what you are looking for: cleanly indexed computer science conferences and journals with citation counts and year, with extensive coverage of computer science literature. The [IEEE Xplore Digital Library](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/aboutUs.jsp) also has decent coverage of computer science literature, though nothing comparable to the ACM Digital Library, and I'm not sure if it includes citation counts.

Also, take a look at [arXiv](https://arxiv.org) for grey literature (that is, not yet published): its computer science section seems to be the number one outlet for computer science working papers (kind of like GitHub for scholarly articles).

Comment: Thanks! This is indeed what I'm looking for. There was still one recent conference that didn't seem to be in the database, but the coverage looks overall good.

Answer (score 2):

As commented by [Jon Custer](https://academia.stackexchange.com/users/15477/jon-custer), [Web of Science](https://webofknowledge.com) has information about citations, conference and publication year in its database and shows it in the results of a search. You can even filter and sort by citations and publication year. Unfortunately, Web of Science is a commercial service and your institution needs to have an agreement with Clarivate Analytics (the provider of Web of Science) to grant you access to the database.

Comment: Thanks. I'm trying it out right now. I'm getting disappointing results for my field. My advisor has around 250 publications and it can only find 27: in particular it seems to be missing most conference proceedings. I also cannot find most papers I try searching just by title. Maybe there is a reason it is not used in my field. Probably it would have been better to ask a question on a site or forum specifically for computer science.

Comment: Mathematics and Computer Science are in fact special cases for this database which covers all other STEM disciplines relatively well. You could also try to ask an expert in bibliometrics at your institution. You may find one in your library.